# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `map' for #<GuestServer:0x00000006a46ae0>):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i got this error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `map' for #):
     8:   
     9:    
    10:   
    11:   
    12:    
    13:   
    14:      'btn-primary' %>
  app/views/guest_servers/_form.html.erb:11:in `block in _app_views_guest_servers__form_html_erb___3580975132148204073_44804260'
  app/views/guest_servers/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_guest_servers__form_html_erb___3580975132148204073_44804260'
  app/views/guest_servers/new.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_guest_servers_new_html_erb___2287482652647252833_55765520'
```

when i add this line of code

```
<pre>
  <%= select_tag "sippeer_type", options_from_collection_for_select(@guest_server, "id", "name") %>
</pre>
```

Comment: What is in the `@guest_server` variable, paste the code

Comment: Could you show the code where you assign the values to `@guest_server`?

Comment: Give me more details, may be some lines of code from  app/views/guest_servers/_form.html.erb:11

Comment: `@guest_server` sounds like one object and not like a collection. is it true?